# How to remove button glow on Video.js player template

Tags: css, video.js, box-shadow

I've been modifying the default [video.js template](http://codepen.io/heff/pen/EarCt), and would like to remove the button 'glow' on hover. I've tried adding a simple `box-shadow: none !important` to several classes in the CSS, with no luck.

Is there another way I should be going about this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The glow is a `text-shadow`.

```
.video-js .vjs-control:focus:before, .video-js .vjs-control:hover:before, .video-js .vjs-control:focus {
  text-shadow: none;
}
```